# C++/CLI: preventing garbage collection on managed wrapper of unmanaged resource

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, c++-cli, finalizer

I have a C++ unmanaged class `NativeDog` that needs to be used from C#, so I've create a wrapper class `ManagedDog`.

```
// unmanaged C++ class
class NativeDog
{
    NativeDog(...); // constructor
    ~NativeDog(); // destructor
    ...
}

// C++/CLI wrapper class
ref class ManagedDog
{
    NativeDog* innerObject; // unmanaged, but private, won't be seen from C#
    ManagedDog(...)
    {
        innerObject = new NativeDog(...);
        ...
    }

    ~ManagedDog() // destructor (like Dispose() in C#)
    {
        // free unmanaged resources
        if (innerObject)
            delete innerObject;
    }

    !ManagedDog() // finalizer (like Finalize() in C#, in case
    {             // the user forgets to dispose)
        ~ManagedDog(); // call destructor
    }
}
```

All is well, and I use the class like this:

```
// in C++/CLI
// this function is called from C++ code
void MyLibrary::FeedDogNative(NativeDog* nativedog)
{
    ... // (***)
}
// this function is called from C#, passes on the dog to the native function
void MyLibrary::FeedDogManaged(ManagedDog^ dog)
{
    NativeDog* rawdog = dog->innerObject;
    MyLibrary::FeedDogNative(rawdog);
}

// C# client code
void MyFunc()
{
    ManagedDog dog = new ManagedDog(...);
    MyLibrary.FeedDogManaged(dog);
}
```

See what's wrong? I didn't either at first, until very strange things started happening from time to time. Basically if after calling `MyFunc()` the program is paused by the GC while it is somewhere in the native function `FeedDogNative` (marked `(***)` above), it will think the managed wrapper can be collected because it will no longer be used, neither in the C# MyFunc (it's a local variable and will not be used after the `FeedDogManaged` call), neither in `FeedDogManaged`. And so this has actually happened on occasions. The GC calls the Finalizer, which `delete`s the native dog object, even though `FeedDogNative` has not finished using it! So my unmanaged code is now using a deleted pointer.

How can I prevent this? I can think of some ways (e.g. a dummy call pretending to use `dog` at the end of `FeedDogManaged`) but what would the recommended way be?

Comment: I highly recommend using CAutoNativePtr (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/CAutoNativePtr.aspx) to handle lifetime management of the native object, then have your `ref class` focus on exposing functionality to managed clients. (This doesn't replace `GC::KeepAlive`; it replaces manual memory management.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a [`GC::KeepAlive()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive.aspx) call in your `FeedDogManaged` function. Seems like it is an exact use case for that.

Answer (score 4):

In your managed code, add `GC.KeepAlive(dog)` following the call to FeedDogManaged():

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive(VS.71).aspx

Comment: That's what I need, although as max said, it's better to put the call _inside_ FeedDogManaged() because it's not the responsibility of the caller of FeedDogManaged() to handle this.

Comment: Yup, agree completely. Didn't read it carefully enough the first time.