# Garbage Collection in C++/CLI, C# Mixed Code

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, c++-cli

I am passing an array by reference from C# to C++/CLI to use as an out parameter. My code is as follows:

C#

```
ushort[] a = new ushort[1];
cppclr.method(ref a);
```

C++/CLI

```
void method(array<ushort>^% a)
{
   a = gcnew array<ushort>(5);
   a[0] = 1;
   a[1] = 2;
   a[2] = 3;
}
```

The code compiles fine and produces no error. However, I am confused whether the array that I created in C# has been taken care of by the garbage collection? My confusion is that since I am assigning a new memory inside C++/CLI, the previous reference is lost and should be handled by garbage collection. The program doesn't show any memory leaks. Do I need to take care of this situation in any other way?

Comment: I think that the GC will do the work, you're allocating memory using .NET (`gcnew`) and not unmanaged code. I'm not 100% sure though.

Comment: @null I'm allocating memory using `gcnew` inside C++/CLI and that reference is kept. I'm confused about whether the memory created by C# `new` will cause any memory leak?

Comment: seems that I was right, since it's created with .NET the GC takes care of it. It would be a different story with CLI and unmanaged types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is being taken care of. Whether you're running C# or C++/CLI or any other .NET language for that matter, it's the **same runtime** that executes both under the hood. Therefore you get the same GC for both.

As you used `gcnew`, you used the runtime's managed memory allocator. Had you used `new` with an unmanaged array in C++/CLI, you'd have to free it with the `delete[]` operator afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage Collection in C# is automatic for **managed resources**, so you should not worry about them. I don't have big experience in C++, but from what I'm seeing you are using **Managed C++**.

> The .NET Framework's garbage collector manages the allocation and
>   release of memory for your application. Each time you create a new
>   object, the common language runtime allocates memory for the object
>   from the managed heap. As long as address space is available in the
>   managed heap, the runtime continues to allocate space for new objects.
>   However, memory is not infinite. Eventually the garbage collector must
>   perform a collection in order to free some memory. The garbage
>   collector's optimizing engine determines the best time to perform a
>   collection, based upon the allocations being made. When the garbage
>   collector performs a collection, it checks for objects in the managed
>   heap that are no longer being used by the application and performs the
>   necessary operations to reclaim their memory.

[MSDN Source Garbage Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx)

You should take care only for unmanaged resources.(For C#  they inherited IDisposable and you should call Dispose() method, for C++ call delete[] like @Lucas mentioned).

You can check this question too: 
[Garbage Collection Across C# and C++/CLI Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757937/garbage-collection-across-c-sharp-and-c-cli-objects)

Comment: OP wants a reference to a reference type, so he needs the `ref` :) Alternatively, he could have used `array<ushort>^` instead of `void` as the return type to avoid the need for the `ref`/`%` parameter.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski thanks for the explanation like I said I'm not experienced in C++. I will remove this part.